# Abstract component vs. prop passing

Tags: reactjs

I am building an app for posting tutorials. Two of the components I have are EditTutorialForm and NewTutorialForm. These two components are essentially the same except for the methods componentDidMount and onSubmit.

What seems to make the most sense is to have an abstract component type called TutorialForm and to extend it to make EditTutorialForm and NewTutorialForm.

I have read on the React docs that inheritance is not recommended with React. Would it be "better" to pass the componentDidMount and onSubmit functions as props to the TutorialForm component, as opposed to extending the component itself?

Comment: "passing as props" is really common practice especially once you use `redux`(not a requirement rather fits best). in this case wrapper component that just passes callback prop and load/pass data is named "container"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create one  component and check within something like the following:

For a new tutorial

```
<TutorialForm edit={false}>
```

To edit a tutorial

```
<TutorialForm edit={true}>
```

And in TutorialForm

```
class TutorialForm  extends Component{
    componentDiMount() {
        this.props.edit ? do edit stuff... : do new stuff
    }

    submitForm = () {
        this.props.edit ? submit edit... : submit new
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks!